# Cannot load dependency system.drawing.common in a class in a DLL

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, system.drawing, akka.net

I'm copying my program to a Virtual Machine to see what software I need and which settings I need to have enabled (or disabled). My program is running fine on my work laptop and on my own laptop (older version), but on the VM the program throws an error during run time.

My program is made out of one executable and many DLLs, both the Executable and the DLLs are able to start just fine including using the dependency `system.drawing.common`. But one of the classes in one of the DLLs gives an error that the dependency `system.drawing.common` could not be loaded. Rebuilding the DLL in question doesn't give a warning that something is wrong. See image below for the error I see.

> [ERROR][12/18/2019 11:04:02 AM][Thread 0006]> 
>   [akka://ModulairVisionFramework/user/AcquireImageActor] Could not load file ? 
>   or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, >PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Cause: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly >'System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, >PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, >PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
>     at CameraSystem.Actors.AcquireImageActor.<.ctor>b__2_0(AcquireImage resp)
>     at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Action`1 )
>     at Akka.Tools.MatchHandler.PartialHandlerArgumentsCapture`2.Handle(T >value)
>     at Akka.Actor.ReceiveActor.ExecutePartialMessageHandler(Object message, >PartialAction`1 partialAction)
>     at Akka.Actor.ReceiveActor.OnReceive(Object message)
>     at Akka.Actor.UntypedActor.Receive(Object message)
>     at Akka.Actor.ActorBase.AroundReceive(Receive receive, Object message)
>     at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.ReceiveMessage(Object message)
>     at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.Invoke(Envelope envelope)

What can the cause be that the main executable and the interface of the DLL are both using `system.drawing.common` fine, but a class in the DLL in question cannot use the dependency? And how can this issue be resolved? I have not faced this issue on my work laptop so far or on another computer (older version of my application but still uses `system.drawing.common`).

**EDIT**
In both the executable project as in the DLL in question I'm using the NuGet package manager for `system.drawing.common`. How the package is included:

```
<PackageReference Include="system.drawing.common" Version="4.6.0" />
```

Comment: Instead of posting an image of the exception, could you post the exception text in as a quote? (With a `>` in front of the text)

Comment: @MindSwipe sure, updating the post

Answer (score 1):

I hit this same problem a week or so ago. If this is a .NET core assembly, the way you reference it makes a big difference. Instead of referencing the .NET lib directly (right click -> add reference), use a package reference in the project file:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="4.6.0" />
```

Comment: Sadly this is the way I'm using the dependency, I will update my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Any chance you have multiple versions referenced between the different projects?

Comment: I had this issue before, but AKKA .net doesn't like it, so I have made sure that all the packages have the same version.